# Scala.js import JS script gives error: expected start of definition

Tags: javascript, node.js, scala, scala.js

I have a JS script `script.js` which contains a class `MyType`. I would like to use the class' methods `add()` and `divide` inside a scala script `App.scala`.

Using `Scala.js` and `JSImport` I import `script.js` into `App.scala`.

However when I try to use the `MyType` methods `add()` and `divide` inside the scala script, I get the error `error: expected start of definition`?

Could you please help me identify the problem?

Thanks in advance!

script.js:

```
class MyType {
    constructor(x, y) {

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

    }

    add(z){
        let {x,y} = this;
        return x + y + z;
    }

    divide(z){
        let {x,y} = this;
        return (x + y)/z;
    }
};

module.exports = {MyType};
```

App.scala:

```
import scala.scalajs.js
import scala.scalajs.js.annotation._

@js.native
@JSImport("./script.js","MyType")

class MyType(var x:Double, var y:Double) extends js.Object

object MyApp {
    @JSExport
    def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {
        val added = new MyType(1,2).add(3)
        println(s"my $added") // 1

        val divided = new MyType(4,3).divide(2)
        println(s"my $divided") // 6
    }
}
```

build.scala:

```
name:="JSImports"
version:="0.1"
scalaVersion:="2.11.12"
enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin)
jsDependencies += ProvidedJS/"script.js"
scalaJSUseMainModuleInitializer:=true
```

Comment: What does your sbt (or other build tool) config look like?

Comment: Just updated the code to reflect the sbt build.

Comment: Your setup doesn't seem to make much sense to me. You use `@JSImport`, but your build does not seem to setup `scalaJSLInkerConfig`'s `withModuleKind(...)`, so linking should first emit an error saying that you haven't enabled module support. Also, using `jsDependencies` for something that is a JS module is not going to work. `jsDependencies` is an obsolete system that only handles Scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error *expected start of definition* is a result of a formatting mistake - you cannot have an empty line between `@JSImport` and `class MyType`.

This is most likely because of the way Scala is ending statements / declarations in the absence of semicolons. I do not know exact rules, but an empty line often makes a difference.